# How to wire up a LED Matrix with a Raspberry PI

Tags: gpio, wiring

I'm not sure how to wire up the LED Matrix corrctly. I followed the steps in this guide: https://github.com/hzeller/rpi-rgb-led-matrix/blob/master/wiring.md In this tutorial the matrix has 3 GND pins. But in the wiring diagram below the GND is only connected with 1 pin (pin no. 6). Can I also use the pins 9 and 14 for the other GND or must all GND wires connected with the same pin?

Comment: You are connecting to an led-matrix controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All grounds are the same.  They are all connected to each other internally.  It does not matter if you use one or several. Do what is most convenient.